# call a javascript function within dynamically created html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript file as you'll see in picture below .
In this file i create a html code for my webpage , And In this html i call a function
defined in the javascript file .
But when i run it i get that the function isn't defined .
additional info :

[image: http://s8.postimg.org/nqwv1na6d/js_function.png]

[image: http://s1.postimg.org/mqyu5zalr/js_function.png]

plus the function mentioned ("cButton") is defined in another function inside the javascript file.

```
(function () {
    var thecid = 0;

    function cButton (ii) {
        document.getElementById(ii).style.display = 'none';
        alert('fdgfg');
    }

    $("#subber").on("click", function () {
        var thelm = "#c0"+thecid;
        var newcommhtml = '<div id="c0' + thecid + '" class="cnew clearfix">';
        var ii='c0'+thecid;
        newcommhtml += '<section class="c-content">';
        newcommhtml += '<a href="#" onclick="cButton(\'' + ii + '\');" style="color:black;">x</a>';
        newcommhtml += '<p>' + nl2br(textval) + '</p> </section></div>';        
    });
})()
```

Comment: Why a picture of the code instead of the code itself??

Comment: Please put code instead of picture

Comment: sorry i thought its more comfortable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `onclick` to work, you need your `cButton()` to be accessible globally as a property of the global window object.

Change you code to:

```
window.cButton = function(ii) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: yeah it is thank u very much, actually what Archer suggested also worked but i prefer this answer cause its shorter .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining `cButton` inside the document ready handler, so it doesn't exist outside that.  If you declare the function outside then things can access it later...

```
function cButton(ii){
    document.getElementById(ii).style.display = 'none';
    alert('fdgfg');
}

(function(){
    var thecid = 0;
    $("#subber").on("click", function(){
        var thelm = "#c0"+thecid;
        var newcommhtml = '<div id="c0'+thecid+'" class="cnew clearfix">';
        var ii='c0'+thecid;
        newcommhtml += '<section class="c-content">';
        newcommhtml += '<a href="#" onclick="cButton(\''+ii+'\');" style="color:black;">x</a>';
        newcommhtml += '<p>'+nl2br(textval)+'</p> </section></div>';        
    });
})()
```

Comment: this worked thank u , but i had to accept techfoobar answer cause its shorter :)

Comment: No worries - glad you got it sorted.  I just wanted to explain further :)